# Numpy: assigning values to 2d array with list of indices

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

I have 2d numpy array (think greyscale image). I want to assign certain value to a list of coordinates to this array, such that:

```
img = np.zeros((5, 5))
coords = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]) 

def bad_use_of_numpy(img, coords):
    for i, coord in enumerate(coords):
        img[coord[0], coord[1]] = 255

    return img

bad_use_of_numpy(img, coords)
```

This works, but I feel like I can take advantage of numpy functionality to make it faster. I also might have a use case later to to something like following:

```
img = np.zeros((5, 5))
coords = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]])
vals = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

def bad_use_of_numpy(img, coords, vals):
    for coord in coords:
        img[coord[0], coord[1]] = vals[i]

    return img

 bad_use_of_numpy(img, coords, vals)
```

Is there a more vectorized way of doing that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We can unpack each row of `coords` as row, col indices for indexing into `img` and then assign.

Now, since the question is tagged: `Python 3.x`, we can simply unpack with `[*coords.T]` and then assign -

```
img[[*coords.T]] = 255
```

Generically, we can use `tuple` to unpack -

```
img[tuple(coords.T)] = 255
```

We can also compute the linear indices and then assign with `np.put` -

```
np.put(img, np.ravel_multi_index(coords.T, img.shape), 255)
```

Comment: Cool, thanks @Divikar. Just to add to this, your last method is three times faster than first two, although I am still unsure how exactly it works.

Comment: @ymoiseev Given enough pts in `coords`, the first two should be faster though.

Comment: The first method `img[[*coords.T]] = 255` will now give you warning. It is recommended to use the second method `img[tuple(coords.T)] = 255` now.

Comment: Yep. `Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated` Please remove the first answer and change the text accordingly.

Comment: In v1.23.2,`img[[*coords.T]] = 255` now sets every element of `img` to 255 (not what we want).